# willRotateToInterfaceOrientation + setframe can't layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, layoutsubviews

I'm trying to change the shape of a view right before rotating (without animation but with a CGRect I want to get at that time) and while rotating (with new CGRect).

Basically, iOS won't layout anything in the "willRotateToOrientation" method, even if i try to force it with "self.view layoutIfNeeded", "self.view setNeedLayout", "self.view layoutSubviews" and so on...)

As I'm using autolayout, I tried not to do it with SetFrame but with constraint (didn't change anything at all)

Comment: Can you not set your constraints such that it works in both orientations?  Isn't that half the point of autolayout.

Comment: I need to change the size and position of a view depending on two cells from two different collection view. I select these two cells dynamically depending on the offsets of the collection view before rotating. Autolayout is not a solution for that